# How to create a 3-color gradient dial indicator (the one that shows green-yellow-red)

Tags: pyqt

[image: Dial-with-static-gradient-indicator]

So I have this dial image I'm using for a PyQt widget. Right now, as you can see, the gradient indicator, the arc of green-yellow-red is static and is part of the image.

I want to create this dynamically, so that based on some ranges, the color can be determined. For example, instead of equal parts green and red, I might want about 60 degrees worth of it to be red and the rest green and yellow. For this, I shall specify some range (eg. 0-90 degrees worth should be green etc).

Any ideas on how I can draw such a CURVED color gradient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To accomplish this, one way is to create a widget and do a custom paintEvent. You will build up this result with a couple elements:

1. Draw the static pixmap of the gauge background
2. Draw a pie shape with a gradient
3. Re-fill the center with the original image to cut it back out again

You will need to cache the pixmap once in the init so you don't keep creating it from disk. Then you can give the widget a method to set the value from `0.0 - 1.0`.

```py
class GaugeWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, initialValue=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GaugeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._bg = QtGui.QPixmap("bg.png")
        self.setValue(initialValue)

    def setValue(self, val):
        val = float(min(max(val, 0), 1))
        self._value = -270 * val
        self.update()


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
        rect = event.rect()

        gauge_rect = QtCore.QRect(rect)
        size = gauge_rect.size()
        pos = gauge_rect.center()
        gauge_rect.moveCenter( QtCore.QPoint(pos.x()-size.width(), pos.y()-size.height()) )
        gauge_rect.setSize(size*.9)
        gauge_rect.moveCenter(pos)

        refill_rect = QtCore.QRect(gauge_rect)
        size = refill_rect.size()
        pos = refill_rect.center()
        refill_rect.moveCenter( QtCore.QPoint(pos.x()-size.width(), pos.y()-size.height()) )
        # smaller than .9 == thicker gauge
        refill_rect.setSize(size*.9)
        refill_rect.moveCenter(pos)

        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)

        painter.drawPixmap(rect, self._bg)

        painter.save()
        grad = QtGui.QConicalGradient(QtCore.QPointF(gauge_rect.center()), 270.0)
        grad.setColorAt(.75, QtCore.Qt.green)
        grad.setColorAt(.5, QtCore.Qt.yellow)
        grad.setColorAt(.25, QtCore.Qt.red)
        painter.setBrush(grad)
        painter.drawPie(gauge_rect, 225.0*16, self._value*16)
        painter.restore()

        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(self._bg.scaled(rect.size())))
        painter.drawEllipse(refill_rect)

        super(GaugeWidget,self).paintEvent(event)
```

[image: Quarter value]

[image: Half value]

[image: Full Value]

You can expand on this widget even more by exposing a way to set the colors and also maybe even changing the start and end ranges. They would be attributes that the paintEvent would reference, just like the value attribute it is using now.

You can also adjust the color stop values to change the balance of the ranges.

Make sure to have the paintEvent do as little processing as possible.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. I put your code in my program and it has generated something like this: http://i.imgur.com/ascAo.png
(Don't mind the numbers etc. Crude stuff)
I can see that the gradient curve is there! But the image is kinda untidy and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?
I've set the geometry of the window to `(0, 0, 700, 700)`, would that kind of hard-coding be a problem?

Comment: Hmm. I cant test this at thr moment, but can you check if it looks correct using a 600x600 images and 600x600 window? It doesnt make any size assumption in that example besides the scaling down to fit inside the bezel. If you can pastebin a really simple example of it doing this problem, i can look at it

Comment: I tried the 600x600 window, doesn't work. I don't understand where it si going wrong either. Here's a pastebin of it, it's almost exactly your code, just with a few additions of mine: http://pastebin.com/i4YZN0JS

Comment: Okay, here is the curious thing. I was playing with the generated window + image, and when I resized the window, the distortions disappeared. It went away even when I resized it back to its original size. However, after I minimized the window and opened it again, the distortions were back.

Comment: Ahhh  yikes! You are creating a new pixmap from disk inside the paintEvent? Dont do that. I will write up a fixed example from your pastebin

Comment: Here is a corrected version that does not have any artifacts for me: http://pastebin.com/yN3B3fc2 . You should keep the GaugeWidget as something that can be added as a component to any other layout. I used your `Example` as a "window" and added the `GaugeWidget` to the layout. If it were to also draw text labels, you would then expand on the `paintEvent` of the `GaugeWidget` to do more drawing.

Comment: Thank you! It's beeyootiful. *sniff*